# Как сделать проверку RPC и REST запросов в GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

Имеется frontend сервер на Tomcat с пользовательским интерфейсом на GWT-Platform и backend сервер на Google AppEngine с бизнес логикой. Запросы выполняются как через gwtp-dispatch-rpc-client так и через gwtp-dispatch-rest. Авторизация происходит через OAuth. Раньше, когда все было на одном сервере использовались сессии, сейчас сделать с помощью сессий не получается.

Есть идеи как делать такие защищенные запросы с frontend на backend?

**UPD**

На backend'е сессии работают. Не ясно как я узнаю на нем, что запрос пришел именно от этого клиента, ведь в запросах не передается никакой информации, по крайней мере в rpc-dispatch. С REST, я думаю, проще потому, что я могу отправить токен сессии в самом запросе, а что делать с RPC, я не знаю.

Вопрос стоит даже шире: *как в RPC-Disptch указать, что запрос нужно делать не на тот же сервер, а на совсем другой адрес и как в запросе передать токен, полученный в результате авторизации.*

Я предполагаю после OAuth авторизации редиректить на frontend с токеном, например, полученным из сессии. А дальше, передавать этот токен в каждый запрос.

Comment: Не понятно в чем твоя проблема. Сессия у тебя должна быть независимо от того, где твой frontend. Разъясни свой вопрос более подробно.

Comment: Спасибо, уточнил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сервер узнаёт клиента по куке. Для `Java` это `JSESSION`, хотя это не является строгим правилом и можно напилить свою систему сессий. Считается что куку нельзя перехватить (т.к. ты должен использовать **https**, если у тебя есть аутентификация) и подделать (т.к. это набор из более чем 30 случайных символов).
2. С `GWTP` никогда не работал, но касательно `GWT RPC` могу сказать, что оно и служит для того, чтобы не делать явный маппинг запросов по `url`. Собственно поиск вызываемого сервиса на стороне сервера происходит при помощи дополнительного **http-заголовка** (точно сказать не могу), который приходит с клиента. Т.е. все запросы идут на один `url`, а дальше движок `GWT` ищет класс и метод, который надо вызвать, при помощи рефлексии. Поэтому повернуть клиента на другой `url` при помощи `RPC` во время вызова не получится. Тут только явно самому создавать запросы и отправлять их. Можно воспользоваться [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html).
3. Касательно сессий вообще отдельная история. Если ты сможешь передать запрос на другой сервер, то он не будет знать о сессии первого сервера. Можно попробовать шарить сессию первого сервера, но это гиблый путь. OAuth-токен вообще не рекомендуется передавать на клиента. Остается лишь делать дополнительную авторизацию на втором сервере. Её можно сделать фоном, точнее так, чтобы клиент не видел. Хотя на стороне клиента будут редиректы при запросе на второй сервер. Но это всё сработает только в том случае, если у тебя всё на одном домене. Собственно это вопрос отдельной темы.

Comment: Понятен только первый пункт.

Что касается второго, то в `GWT` можно сделать [так](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/TFZsxQIeQXs/cAs3uKbzZ84J)

Третий пункт не совсем понял.

Comment: @AlexPo, по ссылке из второго пункта описан механизм внедрения cors, что мало относится к данному вопросу. Касательно третьего, то задавай уточняющие вопросы.

Comment: А разве я не делаю Cross Origin Request с одного домена на другой?

Comment: @AlexPo нет, ты делаешь редирект на другой домен

Comment: я делаю запрос на другой домен с целью получения данных

Comment: @AlexPo тогда это уже не относится к части OAuth